# Prettyfaces unable to find matching navigation case

Tags: jsf, faces-config, prettyfaces

I keep getting this error:

> Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id `'/index.xhtml'` for action `'/faces/index.xhtml'` with outcome `'finish_setup'`

The program works, redirecting my url to `/Setup` on form submission. However, this error always pops up despite me not having a `faces-config.xml`. When I do include a `faces-config.xml`, the program breaks. I want the form submission to go to the next page as `/Setup`, not as `/faces/setup.xhtml`. I am using PrettyFaces with JSF 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

This error basically means that you don't have a `/finish_setup.xhtml` file. Fix it accordingly. Perhaps you typo'ed the file name or didn't understand the working of JSF 2 implicit navigation.

Comment: also, I believe that both of these files need to be in the same folder.

Comment: @paul: Indeed. The `/faces/*` is typically the `FacesServlet` mapping itself. The path in my answer is relative to the webcontent root.